# Why no methods defined for named pointer types?

Tags: go

In the documentation for [effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#pointers_vs_values) it states:

> As we saw with ByteSize, methods can be defined for any named type
>   (except a pointer ...

```
type ByteSlice []byte
func (slice ByteSlice) Append(data []byte) []byte {
  // Body exactly the same as above
}
```

It then goes on to provide an example with a pointer as receiver:

```
func (p *ByteSlice) Append(data []byte) {
  slice := *p
  // Body as above, without the return.
  *p = slice
}
```

Doesn't that contradict ? Or does it mean that this isn't valid:

```
type ByteSlice []byte
type Pb *ByteSlice
func (p Pb) Append(data []byte) []byte {
}
```

Though it looks just like a typedef!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Named pointer types could lead to ambiguities like so:

```
type T int 

func (t *T) Get() T { 
    return *t + 1 
} 

type P *T 

func (p P) Get() T { 
    return *p + 2 
} 

func F() { 
    var v1 T 
    var v2 = &v1 
    var v3 P = &v1 
    fmt.Println(v1.Get(), v2.Get(), v3.Get()) 
}
```

In the last case (esp. `v3`) per the current spec, it's ambiguous which `Get()` method should be called. Yes, there's no reason that the method resolution couldn't be defined, but it's one more detail to add to the language for something that already has a solution.

Comment: We're speculating about the semantics of something not in the language, but it would be very surprising if conversion from *I to *P happened automatically (and so your snippet is unambiguous). If `P` was defined as `type P I`, then `I(0).Get()` is already unambiguous and I don't see why adding pointers would make any difference.

Comment: I would've gone for P.Get

Comment: @PaulHankin: yeah, that wasn't as clear as I would have liked. I expanded it a little to emphasize the automatic type conversion problem. Note that there's no definitive reason it *couldn't* be defined, but because it doesn't solve a real problem, and only makes the code less clear, it never passed as a feature worth adding to the language.

Comment: The receiver type must be of the form T or *T where T is a type name. The type denoted by T is called the receiver base type; it must not be a pointer or interface type and it must be declared in the same package as the method.

Answer (score 3):

A named type that is a pointer isn't the same as a pointer to a named type.

This is what the language reference says:

> That parameter section must declare a single parameter, the receiver.
>   Its type must be of the form T or *T (possibly using parentheses)
>   where T is a type name. The type denoted by T is called the receiver
>   base type; it must not be a pointer or interface type and it must be
>   declared in the same package as the method.

That's clear enough: if T denotes a pointer type, then you can't use it as a method receiver.

Note the careful language of the reference here: the phrase "Its type must be of the form T or T*" refers to the syntax-level specification of the method receiver (that is, the "form" of the type). That's different from the phrase "The type denoted by T", where it's talking about the type that T names (that is, what the type "denotes").

Comment: Clear enough that's what the document for effective Go and the language specification says. The question is why ?

Comment: I expect the answer would be along the lines of it would make the language more complicated and it's not clear what the benefit would be.

Comment: Fair enough. The other answer does provide one example of potential complication. Naively, type just looks like a typedef to me - not clear why there should be restrictions on the usage.